# Set positive and negative buttons both in the same line in an Alert Dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

For API 16 the positive and negative buttons come one below the other. While in API 19 and above they come in the same line. Changing the font does not change the position. How can I get both the buttons to be in the same line?

[image]

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.resume_session)
            .setMessage(R.string.session_question)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.continue_session, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    setDataAndStart(dataHelper, exDB);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.restart_session, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    exDB.resetCurrentWorkoutRecords();
                    setDataAndStart(dataHelper, exDB);
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog pendingWorkoutAlert = builder.create();
    //check for dp size of the phone and then change font
    if (AppApplication.displayType.equals("normal")) {
        pendingWorkoutAlert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button btnPositive = pendingWorkoutAlert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                btnPositive.setTextSize(14);

                Button btnNegative = pendingWorkoutAlert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                btnNegative.setTextSize(14);
            }
        });
    }
    return pendingWorkoutAlert;
```

Comment: You can use the support library's AlertDialog class or DialogFragment class.

Comment: Please show your xml

Comment: @barq i have added the code. There is no xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying your own layout and thus Android uses the default one, so that you can't influence how the content of your dialog is wrapped.

You can use [AlertDialog.Builder#setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(int)) to define your own layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you might want to adjust the width so that the text labels fit):

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new AlertDialog.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if(textView != null) textView.setTypeface(Utility.getRegularFont(getContext()));

        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setWidth(50);
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setWidth(50);
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setGravity(Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_theme_color));
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_theme_color));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create your own custom dialog

public class DeleteSurveyDialog {
    private Dialog mPopDialog;

    private static DeleteSurveyDialog mInstance;

    private DeleteSurveyDialog() {
    }

    /**
     * This method returens the current class object and check object is null or not
     * if null then reinitialize the object otherwise return the exixting
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static DeleteSurveyDialog getInstance() {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DeleteSurveyDialog();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /*
     * This method display a message or alert for any functionality
     */
    public void displayDeletepopupDialog(final Context mContext, String title, String message) {
        mPopDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        mPopDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mPopDialog.setContentView(R.layout.survey_delete_popup);
        mPopDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        TextView mTextViewTitle = (TextView) mPopDialog.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        mTextViewTitle.setText(title);
        TextView mTextViewMessage = (TextView) mPopDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        mTextViewMessage.setText(message);
        Button mButtonOK = (Button) mPopDialog.findViewById(R.id.deleteSurveyButton);
        ImageView mButtonClosePopup = (ImageView) mPopDialog.findViewById(R.id.closePopButton);

        mButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });
        mButtonClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPopDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        mPopDialog.show();
    }


survey_delete_popup:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ly_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/recyclerdataitemcolor"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/deletesurvey"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:background="@color/line_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/deletesurveymessage"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deleteSurveyButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/messageTextView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/dialogbuttonselector"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closePopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/popup_cross"
        android:translationZ="12dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```